# Button changes color in half

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <h1>Site Name</h1>
  <div class="navbar  navbar-inverse">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button class=" btn btn-primary navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsive-menu">
      <span class="sr-only">Open Navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Point 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Point 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Point 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Point 4</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Ok there is a question.When u hover  button change the half of color to black.When u click the changed color saving.How i cant solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/gsv9po8f/

```css
.btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:hover{
  background-position: 0;
  background-color: rgb(38, 90, 136) !important;
  outline: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <h1>Site Name</h1>
  <div class="navbar  navbar-inverse">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button class=" btn btn-primary navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsive-menu">
      <span class="sr-only">Open Navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Point 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Point 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Point 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Point 4</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```